# Blocking websites on Windows OS machine: registry vs firewall

Tags: http, windows-registry, windows-firewall, blocking

When attempting to block a particular website (e.g. www.facebook.com) on a Windows XP 64bit Professional SP3 machine there are a number of methodologies that can be employed. Some methods are clearly weak (blocking through Internet explorer) but it is hard to see where some other approches may be better or worse than one another.

In particular, does anyone know the positives and negatives of using [Windows Firewall](http://techtips.salon.com/block-access-website-using-microsoft-windows-firewall-1411.html) versus using the [registry](http://www.ehow.com/how_5591940_use-registry-block-websites.html) to block particular sites? Both approaches seem mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a service from the likes of OpenDNS or Google DNS?  They are free and allow you to better control internet access to all kinds of sites.